# Find the dimension of the image of the operator f. Linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ be a linear operator taking a vector with coordinates $(x; y)$ to a vector with coordinates $(x; 0)$. Find the dimension of the image of the operator $f$. How can i do it? I am confused. Tell me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space and interpreting a linear map as just a homomorphism then this just becomes an application of the first isomorphism theorem for vector spaces.

$$ \mathbb{R}^2/ \textbf{ker}(f) \cong \mathbb{R}^2/ \left(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}\right) \cong \mathbb{R} \cong \textbf{Im}(f) $$

Comment: Thank you a lot! I found this theorem, but i don't understand how can i apply it in my example(  I don't understand how can i solve it and get the answer.

Comment: Okay so how you use the theorem is, first make sure you have a homomorphism i.e linear map. And all that's left after that is to compute the kernel of that map and it's image. Typically one has great speculation of what the image is, so you really end up just show $f$ maps onto the thing you are asserting to be the image.

Answer (score 0):

find a basis for the image subspace. one such basis  clearly seen is $(1,0)$ here. Hence the range space is 1 dimensional.